# Why is SQLMetal.exe generating different results for SQL Compact 3.5 and SQL Express 2008 (foreign keys are missing)

Tags: c#, foreign-keys, sql-server-express, sqlmetal

Here's the story: I created a SQL Compact 3.5 database and used SQLMetal.exe to generate DataContext for it. It worked well, but soon I realized that it simply does not suit my needs so I decided to go for SQL Express 2008. I fired up the very same SQL script I used for the Compact to create schema and then fired up SQLMetal.exe tool. I didn't expected the generated DataContext to be different, but I was missing all the relations for some reason.

Here's the SQL Compact commandline:

```
SQlMetal.exe /code:MyCode.cs MyDatabase.sdf
```

And here's the SQL Express 2008:

```
SQlMetal.exe /code:MyCode.cs /server:MyServer /database:MyDatabase
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Try SQL Server 2005. It should work fine.

Comment: SQL2008 supports additional syntax not present in earlier versions, hence the syntax may differ.